# Line follower robot using atmega8

Tags: avr, atmega

I Am new to AVR programming. I am trying to build a Line follower robot using atmega8 which can park itself when both the infrared sensors detect black . my sensors are connected to the `PORTD2` and `PORTD3`, and my Motors are connected to `PORTB0` and `PORTB4` . I planned on running and then delaying the motor for 3 second and the switching them off but the robot has started to work haphazardly. Please help me find out what is wrong with my code.

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
int main()
{
    DDRD=0b00000000;
    DDRB=0b11111111;
    uint8_t sensor;
    uint8_t A= 0b00000000;
    while(1)
    {
        A=0b00000000;
        sensor = PIND;
        A= sensor|0b11110011;
        switch(A)
        {
        case 0b11110011:
            PORTB=0b00010001;
            _delay_ms(3000);
            PORTB=0b00000000;
            break;
        case 0b11111011:
            PORTB=0b00000001;
            break;
        case 0b11110111:
            PORTB=0b00010000;
            break;
        case 0b11111111:
            PORTB=0b00010001;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of sensors is it exactly? Are they really falling below the active low voltage when "dark"? Also, you may want to only check relevant pins, not the whole port. You declare the whole port D as inputs and some of those could be floating and give you unexpected values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring sensor as volatile:

`volatile uint8_t sensor;`

Comment: I don't see how this should accomplish anything. There is no asynchronous context and no multi-byte variable involved.

Comment: "sensor = PIND" is an asynchronous context... the value of PIND changes outside the while loop.

Comment: But since `PIND` is already defined as volatile "under the hood", isn't that sufficient for the compiler to suppress assumptions regarding the value of `PIND` and thus not optimize the assignment to `sensor`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling with any optimization, the delay functions don't work properly.

Otherwise, it looks straightforward, depending on the details of the sensors and motors. What is erratic about the behaviour?